svelte $state considered undefined by eslint?
My code runs fine which makes me think it comes from the linter. Also, when I close the file in VScode it's green, but when I open it it goes red. in my shared.svelte.js file:

Here are the dependencies after npm update :
        "@types/eslint": "^9.6.0",
        "eslint": "^9.0.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-svelte": "^2.45.1",

